# Excel VBA code returns error

Tags: vba, excel

have an excel file with this vba:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

What this does, when something is inserted on those cells, it converts it to caps. Everything works just fine, just one small problem... the file is used every day by several people, so the inserted data is deleted every day, several times. what happens is if I delete one cell at a time it runs smoothly, if I delete several cells at the same time I get a run time error '13'.

how can i correct this?

Answer (score 5):

Loop through each matching cell in Target when Target is more than a single cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000") Is Nothing Then
        dim trgt as range
        for each trgt in Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")
            With trgt 
                If Not .HasFormula Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    .Value = UCase(.Value)
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End With
         next trgt
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then   **and**    
     For Each trgt In Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000"))     Nice btw

Comment: Thank you @QHarr!

Comment: It will be better if `Application.EnableEvents = False` is moved outside just below `If Not Intersect...' would be better. No need to loop that setting IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do the following (it is cosmetic... @Jeeped's answer is the way to go, consider the example of people pasting into more than one cell at time, but there is no taking account of that now in mine as he has done it!)

```
Option Explicit

 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                On Error Resume Next
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                On Error GoTo 0

                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: to be honest I think @Jeeped's answer is better. I am guessing his can cope with people pasting data into multiple cells in one go

Comment: It does, but the insertion of data is always cell to cell, so it wont add anything to my needs